# javascript operators with arithmetics gives unexpected result

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do arithmetics here. The reason why I do this is to prevent messy if else checks and d is null or undefined sometimes.

However the following code gives me something unexpected. Could anyone tell me what is happening? Thanks.

```
var t = 2;
var d = 2;
t + (d && 1 || 0) // logs 3
t + d && 1 || 0 // logs 1
```

Comment: What arithmetic are you doing here? What results do you expect?  On line 3 and 4 you don't have any equals sign so r he result just goes nowhere. Can you be more specific of what you are trying to do, and what unexpected results you're getting?

Comment: Check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) for JavaScript operator precedence.

Comment: ok thanks. ya turns out logical OR or AND precedence is so low.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Operator priority. If you do `t + (d && 1 || 0)` everything inside the brackets gets called before the addition from left to right.
But if you do `t + d && 1 || 0` the addition gets executed before those logical operators.

So in more detail, lets replace those variables with their numerical values:

1. `2 + (2 && 1 || 0)` becomes `2 + (1 || 0)` becomes `2 + 1` becomes `3`
2. `2 + 2 && 1 || 0` becomes `4 && 1 || 0` becomes `1 || 0` becomes `1`

Note: Any number besides zero becomes `true` when converted to boolean in JavaScript and `true` itself becomes `1` when converted back to a numerical representation. Thats why `a && b` will yield to `b`, whenever `a` is not zero

Comment: `a && b` returns `b` if `a` is truthy. So `4 && 1 || 0` becomes  becomes `1 || 0`, not `true || 0`

Comment: ok I guess I missed something here.. apparently `+` is calculated before the `&&` on the right..

Comment: @NaCl please edit your answer according to @sheilak's comment. The part about converting to and from `true` is incorrect.